# Numbered description list with dot leaders?

Tags: lists, description

### The problem:

I would like to create checklists for an aircraft.  What I'm looking for is a way to create **numbered descriptive lists with dot leaders**.

Essentially, I want [this](http://eikimartinson.com/archives/90-LaTeX-Description-Lists-with-Dot-Leaders.html), with numbers.

[image: dot leaders]

---

### The Code:

I have this code, which I took from the above link:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter]{article}

\newenvironment{specifications}{%
  \let\olditem\item%
  \renewcommand\item[2][]{\olditem##1\dotfill##2}%
  \begin{description}}{\end{description}% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{specifications}
    \item[Input Voltage Range] 36-72 V DC
    \item[Input Current] 80 mA
    \item[Power over Ethernet] 802.3af-compliant Powered Device
\end{specifications}

\end{document}
```

I'm frankly not sure where to begin.  I'm a novice with LaTeX - I'd prefer a simple answer to a complex one, but most of all I want to learn.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi @ChristianHupfer - I've added the MWE, but I see that grayshade has already provided exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the welcome, I'm sure I'll be back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change the `descripton` environment for an `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter]{article}

\newenvironment{specifications}{%
  \let\olditem\item%
  \renewcommand\item[2][]{\olditem##1\dotfill##2}%
  \begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{specifications}
    \item[Input Voltage Range] 36-72 V DC
    \item[Input Current] 80 mA
    \item[Power over Ethernet] 802.3af-compliant Powered Device
\end{specifications}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As per Aditya's comment, the contained `\renewcommand` statement may be simplified to only one, compulsory argument, giving:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letter]{article}

\newenvironment{specifications}{%
  \let\olditem\item%
  \renewcommand\item[1]{\olditem##1\dotfill}%
  \begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}% 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{specifications}
    \item{Input Voltage Range} 36-72 V DC
    \item{Input Current} 80 mA
    \item{Power over Ethernet} 802.3af-compliant Powered Device
\end{specifications}

\end{document}
```

Which of course provides the exact same output.

Comment: Why not simply define `\renewcommand\item[1][]{\olditem##1\dotfill}` without the `##2`?

Comment: @Aditya thanks for the suggestions - I was in fact keeping changes to the OPs MWE to a minimum. Trying to make the `\renewcommand` as easy to understand as possible, I guess one might also write `\renewcommand\item[1]{\olditem##1\dotfill}` making the argument compulsory and requiring to write `\item{Description} Value`.