# dotted separation underlining separation in a list creation

Tags: lists

Does anyone knows how to create a list similar to the picture? i am confused in creation of a dotted separation.

[image]

Comment: You can use `\dotfill`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually you should provide some code show what you have attempted.  However, in this case http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196430/15925 will give you one way to do what you ask.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `\leaders` (a low level command). The spacing between dots can be acted on by changing `0.44em` to another length.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{group-separator={,}}

\newcommand{\data}[2]{%
  \begingroup\csname @afterindenttrue\endcsname % in case it comes after a section title
  \makebox[\datawidth][s]{% spread the contents
    #1\ldotfill#2%
  }\par\endgroup
}
\newcommand{\ldotfill}{%
  \leaders\hbox to 0.44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
}
\newlength{\datawidth}
\setlength{\datawidth}{.8\textwidth}% adjust to suit

\begin{document}

\section{Data}

\subsection{Principal Dimensions}

\data{Wing Span}{\SI{16.9}{ft}}
\data{Length}{\SI{14.0}{ft}}
\data{Height}{\SI{3.3}{ft}}

\subsection{Performance}

\data{Service ceiling}{\SI{12000}{ft}}
\data{Maximum altitude}{\SI{15000}{ft}}
\data{Max endurance}{\SI{5}{hrs}}
\data{Max range}{\SI{185}{km}}
\data{Engine}{\SI{26}{hpwr}}
\data{Fuel}{AVGAS (94--100 Octane)}

\end{document}
```

Most importantly, use a macro for inputting the data, so you can set them in other formats just by changing the definition of `\data`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The common but not so optimal approach is to use `\dotfill`. It is implemeted by `\cleaders` primitive which repeats the boxes (with the dot) in the reserved space and the result is centered in this space. What is bad? The dots are not aligned in the lines one above second. But we have the `\leaders` primitive which repeats the boxes in the reserved space aligned with respect to the outer box (i. e. to the whole line). The lines are aligned one above second thus the dots will be aligned too.

Read the manual about `\leaders` primitive.

Comment: Which manual? TeX book?

Comment: For example TeXbook. Or better manual: "TeXbook naruby" (only in Czech:). Note a very special dot alignment in the table of contents in "TeXbook naruby" (available on the internet). I was so curt in my answer because the question is similarly curt.

Comment: I know that feeling :-) Since the answers are meant not only for the OP (but for all of us), please don't be curt. :-) Oh Czech! Any plans for English version?

Comment: @HarishKumar This book is here many years but the English translation is out of my capability. Unfortunately.